# How to create a new NSArray with the last 30 objects from another NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsarray

I have a NSArray with 493 objects and need to create a new one with just the last 30 objects from the first array.

I know how to create a new array with the first 10 or 30 etc, but the other way around I can't.

I tried using this code:

```
NSArray *tempArray = [qtdPrecos subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange([qtdPrecos count]-30, [qtdPrecos count]-1)];
```

But I got this error:

```
[NSArray subarrayWithRange:]: range {463, 492} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 492]'
```

So any one could help??? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part of the NSRange struct is *length*

Answer (score 0):

In NSMakeRange the first parameter is the start, but the second is the *length* of the range.